# How to safely test WooCommerce api key acces rights?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, rights

For an application I'm building I would like to test if I have both read and write access on the customerkey, customersecret combination I receive.

Is there a specific function which is the least disrupting for testing write access? Or is creating and removing a product the adviced way to go?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create a Tax Class with missing fields. You'll get a validation error if the consumer key has write permission, vs an authorization error if it doesn't.

```
{
    "code": "rest_missing_callback_param",
    "message": "Missing parameter(s): name",
    "data": {
        "status": 400,
        "params": [
            "name"
        ]
    }
}
```

vs

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error",
    "message": "The API key provided does not have write permissions.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```